# PDE - General formula for Laplace equation upon infinite strip.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

The problem is to solve this equation:

$$ (x,y)ϵ[0,L_1]x[0,∞]    $$
$$ Δu = 0       $$
$$ u(x,0) = φ(x)     $$
$$ u(0,y) = α(x)     $$
$$ u(L_1,y) = β(x)     $$

The strategy adopted is to limit the length of the strip to a fixed value $L_2$ and then obtain the solution on the infinite strip by sending $L_2$ to infinity. I had no problem calculating the solution of the finite strip
 $[0,L_1]x[0,L_2]$, however I encountered problems during the limit.

---

Lets start with this secondary problem

$$ (x,y)ϵ[0,L_1]x[0,L_2]    $$
$$ Δu_{L_2} = 0      $$
$$ u_{L_2}(x,0) = φ(x)    $$
$$ u_{L_2}(x,L_2) = ψ(x) = α(L_2) + x/L_1·[ β(L_2) - α(L_2) ] $$
$$ u_{L_2}(0,y) = α(x)    $$
$$ u_{L_2}(L_1,y) = β(x)    $$

First I solve it in the special case $ u_{L_2}(x,0) = φ(x) $ and $u(x,y)=0$ otherwise on the border.

The special case $ u_{L_2}(0,y) = α(x) $ and $u(x,y)=0$ otherwise on the border is calculated by swapping the role of $x$ and $y$.

Simmetry considerations allow to solve the special case $ u_{L_2}(x,L_2) = ψ(x) $ and $u(x,y)=0$ otherwise on the border; the special case $ u_{L_2}(L_1,y) = β(x) $and$ u(x,y)=0$ follows.

To sum up, if $φ_n$,  $α_n$ and  $β_n$ are the *Fourier coefficients* of $φ(x)$,  $α(y)$ and  $β(y)$, then the solution of the secondary problem is

$$ u_{L_2}(x,y)  = ∑_{n=1}^∞ sin( \frac{nπx}{L_1})· exp(- \frac{nπy}{L_1}) ·φ_n     $$
$$   + ∑_{n=1}^∞ sin(\frac{nπx}{L_1})· exp(- \frac{nπ(L_1-y)}{L_1}) · \frac{2}{nπ} [  \frac{α(L_2)-β(L_2)}{L_2} + α(L_2)·(1-(-1)^n)  ]     $$
$$   + ∑_{n=1}^∞ sin( \frac{nπy}{L_2})· exp(- \frac{nπx}{L_2}) ·α_n     $$
$$   + ∑_{n=1}^∞ sin(\frac{nπy}{L_2})· exp(- \frac{nπ(L_2-x)}{L_2}) · β_n    $$

---

What I would like to do now is to affirm that 
$$ u(x,y) = lim_{L_2→∞} u_{L_2}(x,y) $$

My problem is that
$$ \lim_{L_2→∞} exp(- \frac{nπx}{L_2}) = 1 $$
$$ \lim_{L_2→∞} exp(- \frac{nπ(L_2-x)}{L_2})= exp(-nπ) $$
$$ ∄ \lim_{L_2→∞} sin( \frac{nπy}{L_2}) $$

The first infinite sum is unchanged by the limit.  The second transforms into $ ∑_{n=1}^∞ sin(\frac{nπx}{L_1})· exp(- \frac{nπ(L_1-y)}{L_1}) · \frac{2}{nπ}  lim_{L_2→∞}α(L_2)·(1-(-1)^n) $, which is zero supposing that $\lim_{y→∞}α(y) = 0$.  However I have no idea how to solve the limits of the third and the fourth infinite sums.